# Using SVG path syntax in paper.js?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, paperjs

With the [raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) library, paths are described using the SVG path syntax, (e.g. `M98.36,214.208l2.186-1.093V210.2l-3.378,0.117l1.174,4.137L98.36,214.208z`, which provides a very compact way to create a shape (especially if your shape is drawn with an external application such as Illustrator).

I'm interested in using the [paper.js](http://paperjs.org/) library (not SVG-based), but a first look at the documentation seems to show that paths are built step by step through object methods. This is a very different approach ("path building" vs "path description", one could say), not very suitable to my needs.

So: is there a way to use SVG Paths in paper.js? Or a similar "path description" solution?

Reference:

- http://paperjs.org/reference/path
- http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.path

Comment: From a first look it seems like no. I might be wrong tho.

Comment: In fabric.js, you can instantiate paths from string that's in SVG format: `new fabric.Path('M 65 0 Q 100, 100, 200, 0', { stroke: 'red' })`

Comment: fabric.js? Yet another library? Thanks, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use SVG path syntax as described in the [Paper.js reference for `pathData`](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#path-pathData)

```
var pathData = 'M98.36,214.208l2.186-1.093V210.2l-3.378,0.117l1.174,4.137L98.36,214.208z';
var path = new Path(pathData);

path.strokeColor = 'black';

// Scale the copy by 1000%, so we see something
path.scale(10);
```

And here as an example as a [Paper.js Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/VY5BC4JAEIX/yrAQFui4sytqRac6FgRCJy/rtiC4uWJLUdF/TwsP3ebx8b43L9aqi2ErVjTG65qFTLvzmG+qh075eqe8gg0Eh2WOMg0FJSh4bgVSnkaEfClPgjgKG0mUWR5yJMosIWVJmCDJbP9XfAbrsp3cg7c1dzgO53zaWgy8bMeEV9+7xmyddf34QWWVboIvjmMotLIGfG1Au+4B1QOIcz5bTd0Rz4n/dOz9AQ==)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a closer looks. A welcome addition to Paper.js.